# PHP mysqli create select boxes

Tags: php, mysqli

I have some code that builds a select box. For the first select box; The selected option has a value of 1 then display it as selected then list everything else that doesn't hold the same value. Works good except the second box doesn't work. It obviously doesn't like me duplicating then changing the values. The second select box is looking for any values with 2. A third one would be a value of 3 etc.

Any way I can get the two of them working together?

```
<select name="first-box">
<?php
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {        
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        if($row['my_value']==1) { 
            echo "<option value='1' selected>" . $row["title"] . "</option>"; 
        } else if ($row['my_value']!==1) {
            echo "<option value='1'>" . $row["title"] . "</option>";
        }
    }
}
?>
</select>

<select name="second-box">
<?php
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {        
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        if($row['my_value']==2) { 
            echo "<option value='2' selected>" . $row["title"] . "</option>"; 
        } else if ($row['my_value']!==2) {
            echo "<option value='2'>" . $row["title"] . "</option>";
        }
    }
}
?>
</select>
```

Comment: I think you have a typo in second select box.
"may_value"

if($row['may_value']==2)

Comment: @Harshad Shettigar yeah it's a typo. Updated. still no joy.

Comment: You have already traversed through the result set once, so you'll have to reset the pointer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help

```
<?php
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {        
mysqli_data_seek($result,0);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    if($row['my_value']==2) { 
        echo "<option value='2' selected>" . $row["title"] . "</option>"; 
    } else if ($row['my_value']!==2) {
        echo "<option value='2'>" . $row["title"] . "</option>";
    }
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to have more than one or two, then reading the data into an array and looping through that as needed will be better/easier

```
<?php
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {        
    $data=$result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}
// stop php and do the <select> tag here or print() it
foreach($data as $row) {
    if($row['my_value']==1) { 
        echo "<option value='1' selected>" . $row["title"] . "</option>"; 
    } else if ($row['my_value']!==1) {
        echo "<option value='1'>" . $row["title"] . "</option>";
    }
}
// stop php or print() a </select>
// stop php and do the <select> tag here or print() it
foreach($data as $row) {
    if($row['my_value']==2) { 
        echo "<option value='2' selected>" . $row["title"] . "</option>"; 
    } else if ($row['my_value']!==1) {
        echo "<option value='2'>" . $row["title"] . "</option>";
    }
}
// stop php or print() a </select>
```